# How can I get a non-static field from the main App.xaml.cs class via App.Current in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to get a non-static field from `App.xaml.cs` class, but i don't know how.

this is my code from `App.xaml.cs` containing the `IsUserLoggedIn` field:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    internal bool IsUserLoggedIn { get; private set; }
}
```

and this is the code calling the `IsUserLoggedIn` field from my `EventTable.cs` class:

```
internal class EventTable
{
    private void UpdateEvents()
    {
        if (App.Current.IsUserLoggedIn) // here is an error: "Applcation"
        {                               // does not contain the definition
                                        // of "IsUserLoggedIn"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`App.Current` is the same static property as `Application.Current` and has declared `Application` type. you need to cast it to `App`. I suggest to do it this way:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    internal bool IsUserLoggedIn { get; private set; }

    public static App Instance
    {
        get { return Current as App; }
    }
}
```

then use it in condition:

```
internal class EventTable
{
    private void UpdateEvents()
    {
        if (App.Instance.IsUserLoggedIn)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should change internal to public: `public bool IsUserLoggedIn { get; private set; }`

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, your answer helped. I just didn't notice at first that the call should now occur via App.Instance and tried to call via App.Current.